# How can I write an array generator that generates numbers in certain column values?

Tags: java, arrays, random, generator

Hi there :) I wrote this array generator and would like to rewrite it so that you can set the value ranges from which the individual column values come.

So as an example: the first columns are either 0 or 1, the values to the right of them are either 3 or 7 and the values of the other columns are between 0 and 1 (so as it is at the moment for all numbers).

1 ; 3 ; 0.68618 ; 0.98135 ; 0.25489 ; ...

1 ; 7 ; 0.32481 ; 0.25871 ; 0.14697 ; ...

0 ; 7 ; 0.96125 ; 0.36815 ; 0.24863 ; ...

......

```
public class scratch{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double values[][] = new double[10][19];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {

                values[i][j] = ((double) (Math.random()));
                System.out.print(values[i][j]+" ; ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

PS: please excuse my bad english

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't know, how to rewrite it / make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check index of column while iterating, first column is when `j == 0` and second column is when `j == 1`. And to alternate between 0 and 1 or between 3 and 7 just create a random number and if it is less than 0.5 take 0 and if not take 1 (or 3 or 7 respectivley)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double values[][] = new double[10][19];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            if(j==0){
                values[i][j] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
            }
            else if(j==1){
                values[i][j] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 3 : 7;
            }
            else{
                values[i][j] =  Math.random();  // to round it to 4 decimal places: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / 10000;                
            }
            System.out.print(values[i][j]+" ; ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can extend this aproach

```
if(j==0){
    values[i][j] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

to choose one number out of four (below between [23, 42, 69, 1001] ) by using something like:

```
if(j==0){
    double x = Math.random();
    values[i][j] = x < 0.25 ? 23 : x < 0.5 ? 42 : x < 0.75 ? 69 : 1001;
}
```

But this will quickly become illegible, especially if you want to choose from even more numbers later on. Therfor I would suggest you to store your possible values in an array and randomly select an index. This way you can add more values if necessary and doesen't need to change the code each time:

```
if(j==0){                
    int[] myValues = {23, 42, 69, 1001};
    values[i][j] = myValues[ (int) (Math.random()*myValues.length)];
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much :) One question to this line: values[i][j] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1; how can I output one of 4 numbers (and not one of 2)?

Comment: Thanke u again :)

Comment: If I want to output one of the 4 numbers for j == 0 and j == 1, but these two numbers must not be the same - how do I do that? (as an example: j == 0 returns 23 and j == 1 returns either 42, 69 or 1001 (but is still random))